# Change a Function if there are object there

Tags: javascript

Example I have a Function that has objects there

```
x; //return {[Function x] a:"hehe", b:123}
```

while i did this

```
x = function(){console.log("hello world");}
```

all objects lost and it become and just have the function alone

```
x; [Function x]
```

I want to change the Function there without reconstructing everything. 
How can I do that?

Comment: please add the constructing of starting `x`.

Comment: Assuming the following problem https://jsfiddle.net/1ujk5h6c/, then I would recommend rethinking the structure of the program. The strategy pattern would be sufficient in this case. For my own challenge I've tried to alter the function while keeping the rest of the "`this`" intact. [This is what I came up with](https://jsfiddle.net/q6hoe2Lg/1/), but I wouldn't use it anywhere near production.